# Angular JS Issue

Tags: angularjs, datatable, datatables

I want to edit row of data table(which is coming from some rest api call,the data in datatable is populated through angular js).

My Question is I need to add one input field in each row and when I submit then all the data will go and save in the database.So can you guys help me adding input field  and when I submit then how to get all the datatable data and make a JSON request.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBhwP.png)
Please refer the image and I need to add input field in notes column and when  press save button then it should take all the 7 datas in datatable and make a json request.

javascript Code:

```
vm.dataTableInstance = $('.datatable-basic').DataTable({
data : priorityAttrs,
columns : [
           { data: 'priority', title : 'Priority', width : '10%' },
           { data: 'attrName', title : 'Attribute Name', width: '30%' },
           { data: 'notes', title : 'Notes' },
           { data: null, orderable : false, width:'5%', render : function(data, type, row){
               return '<ul class="icons-list"><li class="delete-user text-danger-600" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().deleteAttribute(this, \''+data.attrName+'\')"><a><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></li></ul>';
           }}
],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Angular-Xeditable for add data tables. please refer [this](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row) document.

1. install xeditable

   bower install angular-xeditable
2. Include angular-xeditable into your project

3. add "xeditable" to dependencies

   var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);